# android studio doesn't show compiler suggestions

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 0.8.14 and was immediately aware to the face that it doesn't show me suggestions, instead it only pops - "Cannot resolve symbol X".

[image]

I'm using it on OS X.

I already tried to google it and found the following solutions:

1) Check that the "File->Power Save Mode" isn't selected.
2) In "Preferences" - that the "Android" intentions are selected.
3) Reinstalling it, after deleting all the cookies and local library files.

None of them solved it for me :/

Comment: Even if you force with CTRL+SPACE/CMD+SPACE?

Comment: @nunofmendes yes it still doesn't shown. It suggest me some irrelevant suggestions like "clone()" because cl is a substring of it. But not the correct suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily this question is not relevant anymore since google has released Android Studio 2 on Frbruary 2016. I recommend using that version since it's much more stable and works faster then the 1.x.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the cursor on the word with the error, a little icon should appear to the left of that line of code. If you click on that you should see the suggestions.

Comment: in the image above, though you cannot see the curser, it's actually on the "cl" variable and no icon appears in the left bar.

Answer (score 0):

i use mac and had the same problem. i figured out that the android studio does show compile suggestions. What you have to do is **click** on the word not just move the cursor on it! To accept it, use alte + Enter. 
this is my first post on Stackoverflow and i hope it works for u;)

Comment: Hi @badbadtomcat and welcome to stack overflow. Your'e suggested solution isn't my "cup of tea" way to coding, I was looking for deeper solution that involves configuration changes of the IDE itself